# solaris 10 + display 2 lines after match by grep?

Tags: grep, sed, solaris, awk

how to match string , and display the two line under the string

for example ( I want to match the "manufacture" string and display the two lines after

```
cat ima.conf   

# the manufacturer or driver author.

com.sun.ima             /usr/lib/libsun_ima.so.1
com.sun.ima64           /usr/lib/64/libsun_ima.so.1
# Format:
#
# <library name>  <library pathname>
#
```

so I will get only the following lines:

```
com.sun.ima             /usr/lib/libsun_ima.so.1
com.sun.ima64           /usr/lib/64/libsun_ima.so.1
```

Comment: Maybe like your previous post on unix.stackexchange ? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52199/solaris-10-display-2-lines-after-match-by-grep/52200#52200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an `awk` solution :

```
grep="pattern" # the string where we begin
max=4          # the number of lines after the matched pattern
awk '/'"$grep"'/{l=1;count=NR;next} l>0 && NR-count < '"$max"+1' {print}'
```

(tested on `Solaris11`)

Answer (score 0):

This one would work on Solaris:

```
ggrep -A 2 'pattern' fileNames.ext
```

For example:

```
ggrep -A 5 -i 'pyCharm' myfile.txt
```

--- which will search for the case-insensitive pattern 'pyCharm' with 3 lines before the match and 5 after the match from the file myfile.txt